# How to count one or more values and display them in a column.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just starting to get a hang of SQL but I've tried to find an answer to this but with no avail.

I have a table that kinda looks like this:

```
 date         base     version      prod_id      place
 2016-01-02   1        1            22           home
 2016-01-02   1        1            22           home 
 2016-01-02   1        1            1            home
 2016-01-02   1        1            1            store
 2016-01-02   1        1            22           store
 2016-01-02   1        1            2            store
 2016-01-02   1        1            2            web
 2016-01-02   1        1            24           web
 2016-01-02   1        1            1            web
 2016-01-02   1        2            24           home
 2016-01-02   1        2            22           home
 2016-01-02   1        2            22           store
 2016-01-02   1        2            1            store
 2016-01-02   1        2            2            web
 2016-01-03   1        1            22           home
 2016-01-03   1        1            22           home
 2016-01-03   1        1            1            home
 2016-01-03   1        1            24           store
 2016-01-03   1        2            24           store
 2016-01-03   1        2            22           web
 2016-01-03   1        2            1            web
 2016-01-03   1        2            2            web
 2016-01-03   1        2            1            web
```

I'm trying to do a query that gives me this

```
 date        base      version      place      1,2       22,24   Total
 2016-01-02  1         1            home       1         2       3
 2016-01-02  1         1            store      2         1       3
 2016-01-02  1         1            web        2         1       3
 2016-01-02  1         2            home       2         0       2
 2016-01-02  1         2            store      1         1       2
 2016-01-02  1         2            web        1         0       1
 2016-01-03  1         1            home       2         1       3
 2016-01-03  1         1            store      0         1       1
 2016-01-03  1         2            store      0         1       1
 2016-01-03  1         2            web        3         0       3
```

So to put it in words: I'm trying to group and count the occurances of each value in prod_id and put them in an column. And its not only one value that needs to be counted and grouped together, sometimes two or more. So in this example i've added up all occurances of 1 and 2 on a specific date, version and place and so also 22 and 24. Do I make any sense?

Comment: Thank you all, would have mark everyone as the right answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice problem. You can count a complicated CASE.
The query

```
 SELECT 
   prod_id,
   CASE WHEN prod_id IN (1,2)   THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS v1Or2,
   CASE WHEN prod_id IN (22,24) THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS v22or24
  FROM table1
```

This gives you something you can usefully SUM

```
prod_id      v1or2       v22or24
22           0           1
22           0           1
1            1           0
1            1           0
22           0           1
2            1           0
2            1           0
```

With the appropriate GROUP BY you have...

```
 SELECT date,place,base,version,
   SUM(CASE WHEN prod_id IN (1,2)   THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS v1Or2,
   SUM(CASE WHEN prod_id IN (22,24) THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS v22or24
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY date,place,base,version
```

Comment: Hi again, that worked like a charm. I wonder what happens if I do a script that potentially could generate over 3000 case ifs in 30 000 rows. Is there an overload risk that could cause damage?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select [Date]
       ,Base 
       ,[version]
       ,place
       ,SUM(Case when prod_id IN (1,2)   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1,2]
       ,SUM(Case when prod_id IN (22,24) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [22,24]
       ,Count(*) AS Total
 From TableName
 GROUP BY [Date] ,Base ,[version],place
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by combining the sum aggregate function with case expressions to do the counts based on what value the prod_id has. This technique is sometimes referred to as *conditional aggregation*.

Try this:

```
select 
 date, base, version, place, 
 sum(case when prod_id in (1,2) then 1 else 0 end) as "1,2", 
 sum(case when prod_id in (22,24) then 1 else 0 end) as "22,24",
 count(prod_id) as Total
from your_table
group by date, base, version, place 
order by date, base, version;
```